# point estimation--an interview

Tags: point-estimation

I've encountered the following interview question:

```
A field with unknown number of rabbits. Catch 100 rabbits and put a label
on each of them. A few days later, catch 300 rabbits and found 60 with 
labels. Estimate how many rabbits are there?
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: capture-recapture problem which can be easy and difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you a hint:

Recall that if you have a finite population with $n_1$ subjects from group 1 and $n_2$ subjects from group 2, if you were to randomly sample a subject from the population, the probability that you get a subject from group 1 is

P(random sample from group 1) = $\frac{n_1}{n_1 + n_2}$

In this case, which of these values are known and which do you have estimates for?

Comment: Good one with some assumptions.

Comment: @CliffAB, thanks so much. Assume that there are x rabbits in total. So P(sample a labeled rabbit) = 100/x. E(sampling 300 times) = (100/x)*300 = 60 ==> x = 500. Am I right?

Comment: Looks right to me!